# Bizarre Behavior of src attribute on img element in VS2008 inserting [A] characters

Tags: asp.net

With VS2008 SP1 I have a line of code like this in an aspx file:

```
<img src='http://spiurl.appspot.com/<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserName") %>' style='border:0; cursor:pointer;'/>
```

This works perfectly.  However, if I switch to "Design" mode in the IDE and then back to "Source" mode the characters **[A]** are magically/infuriatingly inserted into the beginning of the src attribute and I end up with:

```
<img src='[A]http://spiurl.appspot.com/<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserName") %>' style='border:0; cursor:pointer;'/>
```

...which of course is broken.  Has anyone else seen this annoyance before?   Do you have a solution?

Update:   Actually it appears that this happens on every attempt to save the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied a hotfix from Microsoft and the problem went away:

[IDE Serialization Hotfix](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=17185)